# Aggregate same records from two table

Tags: sql, oracle

there has been a situation in Oracle database that I want to create a report from two tables with same columns
Table `A` includes `id, code, name` and table `B` includes `id, code, name` too
Now I want to create a report which counts and group data in both table and gives the result as follow:

`Id1, code1, name1, count (the occurrence of this combination in both tables)`

`Id2, code2, name2, count (the occurrence of this combination in both tables)`

How can I achieve the above result using queries? the important fact is that some times a specific item might not be found in one table, so the total count would be the count which has been found in the other table. possible result would be

`idn, coden, namen, count of occurrence which found in one of the tables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this:

```
SELECT id, code, name, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT id, code, name FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, code, name FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY id, code, name
```

If you want to retain the information how many times each `(id, code, name)` combination appeared in each table, you can use an auxiliary column:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  code, 
  name, 
  count(*) AS "Occurrence in both tables",
  count(CASE WHEN t = 'table1' THEN 1 END) AS "Occurrence in table1",
  count(CASE WHEN t = 'table2' THEN 1 END) AS "Occurrence in table2"
FROM (
  SELECT id, code, name, 'table1' AS t FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, code, name, 'table2' AS t FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY id, code, name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name,count from
(
select id as id , name as name, count as count from table1
union
select id as id , name as name, count as count from table2
)
```

and if you mean to count the results then

```
select count(*) from
(
    select id,name,count from
    (
    select id as id , name as name, count as count from table1
    union
    select id as id , name as name, count as count from table2
    )
)
```